# Quadratic Function Help

Tags: functions, quadratics

Not sure how to solve this one:

> State the value $k$ such that the function $f(x) = -2 (x-3)^2 + k$ has $1$ root.

So I already know that this has to be a sideways parabola, but don't know how to continue.

Comment: Just one root, or two?

Answer (score 5):

For $f(x)$ to have roots we must have $f(x)=0$. This leads to:$$-2(x-3)^2+k=0$$$$\therefore (x-3)^2=\frac{k}{2}$$$$\therefore x=3\pm\sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}$$This should help you see what $k$ must equal in order to obtain just **one** root.

Answer (score 3):

If $k=0$, the only root is $x=3$